# Sync with Xcode option is disabled in Xcode

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin-studio

The `Sync with Xcode` option is disabled in Tools.
How can I fix this?

Note : I use Xamarin Studio v5.10.3 and try to debug my Xamarin application on iPhone 4S.

Answer (score 1):

The Sync with xcode option will enable when you open your project in xcode interface builder as in the image below.[image: how to do that]

And then it will enable your option

[image]

This is used when you use xcode to do the changes in your xib files. The full article is in https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/mac/application_fundamentals/working-with-xibs/

Comment: Thank you but which application is this? I couldn't see an option like this in Xamarin Studio.

Comment: This us xamarin studio in the mac.  There is no other IDE other than Xamarin studio and visual studio.

Comment: I forgot to write, I'm trying on a Forms application.